# Access to device homescreen from AlertDialog

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service, android-alertdialog

I have added an AlertDialog to a Service.

However, when this AlertDialog appears, my Home Screen appears in the background.

When I press "Ok" on my AlertDialog, the notification disappears, however leaves me on my Home Screen of my *application*, when I want to be on the default home screen of my **device**, not application.

```
     String appName = (String) packageManager.getApplicationLabel(applicationInfo);
        if (lockedApps.contains(appName)) {
            showMyDialog();
            Intent dialogIntent = new Intent(this, MyDialog.class);
            dialogIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(dialogIntent);
        }else{
            //Toast.makeText(this, "App in foreground: " + appsInForeground, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        return Service.START_REDELIVER_INTENT;
    }

 public boolean showMyDialog(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    }
```

Does anybody know how I can show my DEVICE home screen and not application homescreen once I click OK button on my alert dialog?